# Random call name in Android

Tags: android

How to make a 'random call' name in List in database sqlite. How can I call one by one without repeating its value. My layout is one textview, If I click the name it will change. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

@PPartisan not working. 
I add button to test the result from textview. 1 row only detected when I pressed back and back to activity the result is the same value. I clicked the button did not work.

```
    rnd  = new Random();
    randomValue =              rnd.nextInt(list.size());
    result =list.get(randomValue).toString();
    list.remove(randomValue);

    btnClick.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){
@Override 

public void onClick(View v){
    tv.setText(result); 
}
});
```

Comment: Yea, because all of the code from `randomValue` onwards needs to be inside your `OnClickListener`, otherwise the values wont refresh on each button click. I did say that in my anawer

Answer (score 0):

Untested, but should be fine:

Query your database, then use the returned `Cursor` to populate a `LinkedList` with whatever options you would like.

```
LinkedList list = new LinkedList();
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
    for (int i = 0; i < cursor.getCount(); i++) {
        cursor.moveToPosition(i);
        list.add(cursor.getString(etc...);
    }
}
```

Create a `Random` object, and use it to select and remove a random element from `list` each time:

```
Random rnd = new Random();

//The below section could be repeated on, for instance, a button click.
int randomValue = rnd.nextInt(list.size());
String result = list.get(randomValue);
list.remove(randomValue);
```

Each time an element is removed, the `LinkedList` will adjust in size to accommodate it, so no results will be repeated.